# CodeDOM - Как внедрить файл в ресурсы компилируемого файла?

Tags: c#, codedom

Использую [CodeDOM](https://www.smarly.net/metaprogramming-in-net/techniques-for-generating-code/generating-code-with-the-codedom/understanding-the-codedom) для компиляции исходного файла (stub.txt) из ресурсов ( в билдере )

У меня есть доп файлы ( бинарный .exe ) который необходимо внедрить в ресурсы компилируемого файла.

Как это сделать?

---

Полный пример Stub и Билдер

**Stub**:

```
using System.Text;
using Test.Properties; // Заранее добавлял в ресурсы файл и так оставил.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Test")]
...
namespace Test
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[Text]");
            ResMethods.Unpack(); // доп метод который извлекает ресурсы его я вырезал.
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

**Builder**:

```
public static void CreateBuild(string text)
{
   string Source = Resources.Test;
   Source = Source.Replace("[Text]", text);
   Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } };
   using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions))
   {
         var parameters = new CompilerParameters();
         // ...
        provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, Source);
   }
}
```

---

Варианты которые я попробовал ( без использования: `using Test.Properties;` )

```
parameters.CompilerOptions += $" /win32res:{Resources.Binfile}";
```

Возвращает ошибку:

> error CS0103: Имя "Resources" отсутствует в текущем контексте

Если же использую `using Test.Properties;`

То Возвращает такую ошибку:

> error CS0234: Имя типа или пространства имен "Properties" отсутствует в пространстве имен "Test" (пропущена ссылка на сборку?)

Подскажите как добавить файл в ресурсы?

---

P.S: На случай если никто не понял, вот что я пытаюсь добиться:

У меня в билдере в ресурсах лежит бинарный файл ( переименовал в Test.txt )
Я хочу чтобы он передался в компилируемый файл Build.exe ( чтобы внутри него был мой файл из ресурса.

Comment: Кто с этим сталкивался? помогите решить.